# How to create 2 or more different RMI remote objects in one interface?(factory Pattern)

Tags: java, rmi

For Example

```
SvrInterface si1 = (SvrInterface) Naming.lookup(Address);
SvrInterface si2 = (SvrInterface) Naming.lookup(Address);
si1.setUser ("User1");
si2.setUser ("User2");
```

And Next

```
String si1User = si1.getUser();
```

Will the result of si1User become "`User1`" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer in your case is No. You're still referencing the same remote object in registry bound to the address. Good place to begin learning more about RMI architecture > [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/rmi/RMI.html).

### EDIT 1

Simple RMI Factory example I whipped up quickly...

#### EchoService

```
public interface EchoService extends Remote, Serializable{
    String echo(String msg) throws RemoteException;
    String getUser() throws RemoteException;
    void setUser(String user) throws RemoteException;
}
```

#### EchoServiceImpl

```
public class EchoServiceImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements EchoService {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3671463448485643888L;

    private String user;

    public EchoServiceImpl() throws RemoteException {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public String echo(String msg) throws RemoteException {
        return this.user + ": " + msg;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUser() throws RemoteException {
        return this.user;
    }

    @Override
    public void setUser(String user) throws RemoteException {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

#### EchoServiceFactory

```
public interface EchoServiceFactory extends Remote {
    EchoService createEchoService() throws RemoteException;
}
```

#### EchoServiceFactoryImpl

```
public class EchoServiceFactoryImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements
    EchoServiceFactory {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 6625883990856972736L;

protected EchoServiceFactoryImpl() throws RemoteException {
    super();
    System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.codebase", EchoServiceFactory.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toString());

    System.setProperty("java.security.policy", "/java.policy");

    if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
        System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
    }

    try {
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("localhost");
        registry.rebind("EchoService", this);
        System.out.println("Echo service factory registered.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error registering echo service factory: "
                + e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public EchoService createEchoService() throws RemoteException {
    return new EchoServiceImpl();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        new EchoServiceFactoryImpl();
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        System.err.println("Error creating echo service factory: "
                + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

#### EchoServiceClient

```
public class EchoServiceClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            System.setProperty("java.security.policy", "/java.policy");

            if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
                System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
            }

            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("localhost");

            EchoServiceFactory serviceFactory =
                    (EchoServiceFactory) registry.lookup("EchoService");
            EchoService echoServiceX = serviceFactory.createEchoService();
            echoServiceX.setUser("Tom");
            System.out.println(echoServiceX.echo("Hello!"));
            EchoService echoServiceY =
                    serviceFactory.createEchoService();
            echoServiceY.setUser("Jerry");
            System.out.println(echoServiceY.echo("Hello"));
            System.out.println(echoServiceX.echo("Hey There!!!"));
            System.out.println(echoServiceY.echo(":o)"));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Running the client produce output as below.

```
Tom: Hello!
Jerry: Hello
Tom: Hey There!!!
Jerry: :o)
```

Comment: Thank you,But is there any way to do with this case?I have apply too many that kind of usage in my project.

Comment: @Shisoft You can apply Factory Pattern with RMI, have a look here http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/rmi/Factory.html. Would you be able to take it from here, or more concrete example would help?

Comment: @Shisoft I have added a simple example I quickly created and tested. Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow,I never think I can use rmi like that.just send it by another remote object ?

Comment: @TMan `java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: 
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.shisoft.rmi.server.UserSvr (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)`
Do I need to do something with security manager?

Comment: @Shisoft My fault,UserSvr is on server side,sorry

Comment: @TMan When it is on a common pack,It works well But are you sure the code in `EchoServiceImpl` is running in server side not client side?

Comment: @Shisoft I trust you have resolved SecurityManager issue, I omitted those lines for simplicity. I am positive about your last question, indeed EchoServiceImpl code downloaded from server.

Comment: You can verify this by doing a simple experiment. Setup 3 projects in your preferred IDE, EchoCommon, EchoServer and EchoClient. EchoCommon to have two interface (EchoService, EchoServiceFactory), EchoServer to have two classes implementing common interface and EchoClient to have the Client class. Add dependency of EchoCommon to Client and Server projects. Compile and Run. This way you will make sure Client have no direct visibility of implementation classes.

Comment: @TMan follow your direction, I got `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: rmitestingserver.EchoServiceImpl` at `EchoService echoServiceX = serviceFactory.createEchoService();`,I solved SecurityManager issue.That's wrong then?

Comment: @TMan If I put EchoServiceImpl in common library,it runs.But runs in client side not server side.This is why I ask you that question.
Java： 1.6.0_22; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 17.1-b03-307
Mac OS X 10.6.6

Comment: @Shisoft Don't put EchoServiceImpl in Common instead try extending EchoService interface with Remote. Let me know. I am trying to run this for like an hour now and stuck at `Exception creating connection to: 192.168.2.1; nested exception is:java.net.SocketException: Cannot allocate memory`. This seems to be known issue for MacOSX http://bit.ly/ccgUbl. Did you encounter this? I am running exactly same VM on OSX as you today and I don't have access to my workstation where I ran this yday. :o(

Comment: I extend EchoService interface with Remote，occurred `NotSerializableException` .I didn't cought `Cannot allocate memory `

Comment: Extending Remote was a long (and terrible) shot, I still have to test that. Meanwhile are you setting java.rmi.server.codebase property when running the server? I'll have something useful to contribute on Monday if you still facing the same issue. I simply can't get past `Cannot allocate memory error`. Even installed Java 6 Update 4 Developer Preview for 10.6 only to ran into same Exception again.

Comment: @TMan I didn't set codebase.Sorry for disturbing your sunday.

Comment: @Shisoft have a good news for you finally! EchoService should extend Remote and EchoServiceImpl UnicastRemoteObject class. Should have been obvious for any code that end up served dynamically via rmi. duh! I have updated code above to reflect this. Also `java.rmi.server.codebase` must be set. Look server code above. There are other ways to set this aswell. Offtopic: There's no way around `Cannot allocate memory error` for me as yet, I installed OpenJDK 7 (beta) for OSX and it worked just fine.

Comment: @TMan Thank you.I found another solution:bind new EchoServiceImpl for each user (of course extends UnicastRemoteObject).what about this?

Comment: @Shisoft I would not recommend binding new instance for each user, how would registry know which instance to retrieve for same address? Even if you workout different addressing it would be highly inefficient. I suggest you look into RMI Activation Framework. This book http://books.google.com/books?id=d9fvFC49TxcC, although bit old now, have a good chapter on Factories and Activation. You can read entire chapter more or less in google book preview.

Comment: @TMan What is the content of `java.policy`?

Comment: @Shisoft for testing purpose, my java.policy looks like `grant {permission java.security.AllPermission; };`. However this is not advisable for production use. It should be more specific.

Comment: @TMan 
Error registering echo service factory: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
        java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: rmitesting.EchoServiceFactory (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)

Comment: @Shisoft The exception occurs if the codebase property is not set correctly. Are you sure you running the code as listed above? Make sure that the both interface in the same package. I have now verified above code on two different machine and platforms. Works just fine.